# How to instantiate a type dynamically using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to instatiate a C# type dynamically, using reflection. Here is my scenario: I am writing a base class, which will need to instantiate a certain object as a part of its initialization. The base class won't know what type of object it is supposed to instantiate, but the derived class will. So, I want to have the derived class pass the type to the base class in a base() call. The code looks something like this:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    protected MyBaseClass(Type myType)
    {
         // Instantiate object of type passed in 
         /* This is the part I'm trying to figure out */
    }
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyDerivedClass() : base(typeof(Whatever))
    {
    }
}
```

In other words, the base class is delegating to its derived type the choice of the object type to be instantiated.

Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx

Comment: Somewhat limited: "Creates an instance of the specified type using that type's `default` constructor." Only the default constructor. This might be more useful when using arguments during construction: Creates an instance of the specified type using the constructor that best matches the specified parameters => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b0ww1we.aspx

Answer (score 25):

You're looking for `Activator.CreateInstance`

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

There are are various overloads of this method that can take constructor arguments or other information to find the type (such as names in string form)

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Jared! I'm going to accept Stuart's answer, since he beat you to the buzzer by a minute. But +1 from me.

Comment: Accept the best answer, not the first! :)

Answer (score 19):

You might want to use generics instead:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T> where T : new()
{
    protected MyBaseClass()
    {
        T myObj = new T();
         // Instantiate object of type passed in 
         /* This is the part I'm trying to figure out */
    }
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass<Whatever>
{
    public MyDerivedClass() 
    {
    }
}
```

The `where T : new()` is required to support the `new T()` construct.

Comment: That's a great solution--I may actually use it in place of Activator.CreateInstance, which is what I was trying to remember. +1 from me.