# C# Expression to dynamically instantiate type without reflection

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a kind of object factory to instantiate a type implementing a specific interface where the type to instantiate is not known before runtime and I'm trying to achive this without using reflection. I've found some examples sugesting this might be possible using Expressions but I've not managed to find an example that works for my case. Might be that it's simply not possible but I wanted to throw the question out here to make sure.

So what I have this far is this:

```
public static Func<Type, object[], IMyInterface> FactoryExpression =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<Type, object[], IMyInterface>>(
        /* Something that creates an instance of the type with given arguments */
    ).Compile()

public static IMyInterface GetTypeOfMyInterface()
{
    Type t = Type.GetType(GetTypeNameFromSomewhere());
    ConstructorInfo c = t.GetConstructors().First();
    object[] args = ResolveCostructorArguments(c.GetParameters());

    return FactoryExpression(t, args);
}
```

I have little exprience with these types of Expressions. Is it at all possible to get this to work or do I have to fall back to reflection?

**EDIT:**

By using Jon Hanna's example I came up with the following:

```
public class TypeInitializer<TResult>
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Func<object[], TResult>> InstanceCreationMethods =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Func<object[], TResult>>();

    public static TResult CreateInstance(ConstructorInfo constructorInfo, params object[] arguments)
    {
        ParameterInfo[] parameterInfo = constructorInfo.GetParameters();
        IEnumerable<Type> parameterTypes = parameterInfo.Select(p => p.ParameterType);
        string constructorSignatureKey = GetConstructorSignatureKey(constructorInfo.DeclaringType, parameterTypes);

        Func<object[], TResult> factoryMethod = InstanceCreationMethods.GetOrAdd(constructorSignatureKey, key =>
                                                                                                         {
                                                                                                             Expression[] args = new Expression[parameterInfo.Length];
                                                                                                             ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]));
                                                                                                             for (int i = 0; i < parameterInfo.Length; i++)
                                                                                                                 args[i] = Expression.Convert(Expression.ArrayIndex(param, Expression.Constant(i)), parameterInfo[i].ParameterType);
                                                                                                             return Expression
                                                                                                                 .Lambda<Func<object[], TResult>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.New(constructorInfo, args), typeof(TResult)), param)
                                                                                                                 .Compile();
                                                                                                         });

        return factoryMethod(arguments);
    }

    private static string GetConstructorSignatureKey(Type type, IEnumerable<Type> argumentTypes) => string.Concat(type.FullName, " (", string.Join(", ", argumentTypes.Select(at => at.FullName)), ")");
}
```

Which seems to work exacly as intended! Thanks a lot for that.
For the sake of experimenting I also made an implementation using Activator.CreateInstance as well as constructorInfo.Invoke and built som performance tests to see the difference..

```
00:00:00.9246614, Actiator
00:00:00.7524483, Constructor Invoke
00:00:00.8235814, Compiled Expression
```

This test timed the creation of 100 000 instances of the same type using each method and printed the result. I was a bit supprised to see that Constructor Invoke method seams to perform better!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to instantiate a type dynamically using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493881/how-to-instantiate-a-type-dynamically-using-reflection)

Comment: Without reflection is what I'm after.

Comment: Oh, my bad then, I saw the GetTypeNameFromSomwhere()... Well I created something once instantiating a type from string, I was getting an ID of the process on a database, and by that ID I was instantiating a new Type
there's something in SO about Instantiating from string, that's where I got it from too :p

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrsteve/archive/2012/02/19/a-fast-c-sharp-extension-method-using-expression-trees-create-instance-from-type-again.aspx) and [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrsteve/archive/2012/01/11/csharp-expression-trees-create-instance-from-type-extension-method.aspx)? That should get you started I think.

Comment: Yes I've solved this kind of issue with reflection as well which is fairly simple. But in this case I'm looking to avoid the performance loss if at all possible.

Comment: @Hintham I will look at that. Seems like I might be able to adapt it to my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Expression.New` to create the instance.

You will also need to pass the `ConstructorInfo` to your factory, and use `Expression.Convert` to cast the object to the interface.

```
public static Func<object[], IMyInterface> BuildFactoryExpression(ConstructorInfo ctor)
{
    ParameterInfo[] par = ctor.GetParameters(); // Get the parameters of the constructor
    Expression[] args = new Expression[par.Length];
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[])); // The object[] paramter to the Func
    for (int i = 0; i != par.Length; ++i)
    {
        // get the item from the array in the parameter and cast it to the correct type for the constructor
        args[i] = Expression.Convert(Expression.ArrayIndex(param, Expression.Constant(i)), par[i].ParameterType);
    }
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object[], IMyInterface>>(
        // call the constructor and cast to IMyInterface.
        Expression.Convert(
            Expression.New(ctor, args)
        , typeof(IMyInterface)
        ), param
    ).Compile();
}
```

> Yes I've solved this kind of issue with reflection as well which is fairly simple. But in this case I'm looking to avoid the performance loss if at all possible.

This is still using reflection. If you are going to use the same `Func` repeatedly **and** you are running in a context where `Compile()` compiles to IL (e.g. not UWP) then you may gain here because reflection is used once to create a re-usable delegate, and from then on it's much the same as if you'd written the delegate as a C# method. You'll gain even more if you can type your arguments rather than passing an `object[]` and have to cast from that.

If you are using these delegates once at a time, you'd be as well to just use reflection. If you are only going to be in a context where delegates from expressions are interpreted, then it's going to have to use reflection internally anyway.